# Jsp File upload returns empty Input Stream for file upload

Tags: java, ajax, spring-restcontroller, fileinputstream

I am working on a jsp file upload using ajax call and I am able to hit the java controller in the HttpServletRequest I see the multipart file received but when I do `request.getInputStream.readAllBytes()`, I get an empty byte array

The ajax call in javascript

```
function saveFileUpload() {
    var data = new FormData()
    data.append("file", document.getElementById(fileName).files[0])

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: pageContext + "/upload",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(e) {}
    });

  }
}
```

In Java controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/upload"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void fileUpload (
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        byte[] arr = request.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
        System.out.println(arr.length);
    }
```

The above code prints `arr.length` as 0. Can someone tell me the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `Springboot` and your application supports `multipart/form-data`. After version **3.0** the Servlet API natively support it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
{
    if (!file.isEmpty()) 
   {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        // and so on
    }
}
```

JQuery's Ajax:

```
function saveFileUpload() {
    let data = new FormData()
    data.append("file", document.getElementById(fileName).files[0])

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: pageContext + "/upload",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(e) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me how can I get the inputStream to get the contentlength of the request

Comment: @Thejas if Spring's `MultipartFile file` works, you can use `file.getInputStream()` method or easily `getSize()` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getSize--

Comment: I am able to get the multipart but I think the content-length is the content length of the request and not the file

Comment: There is no `enctype` field in jQuery ajax. I don't know where/how that started but please stop.  `multipart/form-data` is a content type, which you do not manually set when using a FormData object.